# RecyclerView Adapter's notifyItemRangeChanged is slow?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to update a range of items in my `RecyclerView`. Basically I'm toggling a view between visible/gone for every item in my list. I'm trying to use `notifyItemRangeChanged`, but it's very slow and there is noticeable amount of UI lag. My `onBindViewHolder` isn't super complex either. Is there something I'm supposed to do in the background thread for this?

```
// Called in Activity
mListAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, mPlayerlist.size());


// My adapter's onBindViewHolder method
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PlayerHolder holder, int position) {
    Log.d("onBind", position + "");
    Player player = mPlayerList.get(position);

    if (player.isCheckboxVisible()) {
        holder.checkbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (player.isIncluded()) {
            holder.checkbox.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
        }
    } else {
        holder.checkbox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    holder.playerNameText.setText(player.getName());
}
```

More info as I ran some tests: onBindViewHolder takes about 0-2 ms each, and there are about 5-10 items shown depending on phone size. onBindViewHolder itself looks like it executing pretty fast, but the time for all onBindViewHolder to finish executing in succession is slow. It took .7 seconds for 14 onBindViewHolders to complete. There is like a delay between the onBindViewHolder calls.

Comment: and how long in average `onBindViewHolder` takes to execute per one item? tried to `Log.d` the difference of two `System.currentTimeMillis()`?

Comment: How many items are actually shown in the screen at a time?

Comment: @pskink  onBindViewHolder takes about 0-2 ms each, and there are about 5-10 items shown depending on phone size. onBindViewHolder itself looks like it executing pretty fast, but the time for all onBindViewHolder to finish executing in succession is slow. It took .7 seconds for 14 onBindViewHolders to complete. There is like a delay between the onBindViewHolder calls.

Comment: `".. but the time for all onBindViewHolder to finish ..."` - so how many times `onBindViewHolder` is called? with what `position`s?

Comment: @pskink it binds pos 7-13 then 0-6

Comment: @pskink Well the behavior of the recyclerview is that it binds items off the screen so that when you scroll to it it will be ready for you.

Comment: Changing height of `ViewHolder` inside `onBindViewHolder` will have this behavior as you're forcing `RecyclerView` to go through multiple layout phases.

Comment: @pskink I just figured out the reason why it's so slow is because notifyItemRangeChanged causes too many item change animations to run at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

I just figured out the reason why it's so slow is because notifyItemRangeChanged causes too many item change animations to run at the same time.

Calling `recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null)` makes the call quick and snappy now. Downside is I lose the animations now... =/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I want to avoid using this because this method will make the entire RecyclerView flash which I want to avoid doing. I want to use notifyItemRangeChanged because it will have some nice animations. However I just figured out the reason why it's so slow is because notifyItemRangeChanged causes too many animations to run at the same time.